# Extract data stored in string

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can create an object from this data stored in a string, coming from the google  API:

```
   "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20181213T235959Z;BYDAY=TH"
   ],
```

I can use string methods, but I wondered if there was a better way.

Something like:

```
recurrence: {
    frequency: "weekly",
    until: "yy/mm/dd",
    byday: "th"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the desired object structure, based on the given string?

Comment: You could split on semicolon, which would give you an array of entries.

Comment: No way but string methods for this case.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#recurrence) itself provides no other format. Hence your only option would be to apply simple string transformations. Such as :

```
let targetObj = {};
for(const entry of res.recurrence.substr(5).split(';)) {
    const [key, value] = entry.split('=');
    targetObj[key] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split multiple times and convert key to lower case.

```js
var api = {"recurrence": ["RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20181213T235959Z;BYDAY=TH"]};
var obj = {};
var str = api.recurrence[0];
var arr = str.split(";");
arr.forEach(function(element){

  var pair = element.split("=");
  var key_array = pair[0].split(":");
  var key = key_array[key_array.length-1].toLowerCase();
  var val = pair[1];
  obj[key]=val;
  
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at my solution

```js
var str1 = "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20181213T235959Z;BYDAY=TH";
var str2 = str1.split(':')[1].split(';');
  //  console.log(str2.split(';'));
var x = str2.map((s)=>{
    return s.split("=");
  });

var recurrence = {};
x.forEach((ar)=>{
  if(ar[0] == 'UNTIL')
    ar[1] = moment(ar[1]).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  recurrence[ar[0]] = ar[1];
});

console.log(recurrence);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to match what you want and create your object.

```js
const obj = { reference: ["RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20181213T235959Z;BYDAY=TH"] };

const regex = /\w+=\w+/g;

const extract = (obj) =>
  
  obj.reference.reduce((acc, val) => {
    
    val.match(regex).forEach((match) => {
      
      const [lVal, rVal] = match.split('=').map(d => d.toLowerCase());
      
      acc[lVal] = rVal;
    });
    
    return acc;
  }, {});

console.log(extract(obj));
```